# Does assignment or conditional bind stronger?

Tags: c++, syntax, operators, grammar, operator-precedence

I just stumbled upon the following pair of C++ grammar rules:

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-or-expression
    logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
    throw assignment-expression_opt
```

Note how the rules are mutually recursive: *conditional-expression* refers to *assignment-expression* (rule 2), and *assignment-expression* refers to *conditional-expression* (rule 1).

What does this mean with respect to operator precedence? Normally, the non-terminal for the stronger-binding operator occurs on the right-hand side of the rules for the weaker-binding operator, but not the other way around, right? Here is what puzzles me, specifically:

On the one hand, `a = b ? c : d` means `a = (b ? c : d)`, suggesting `?:` binds stronger.

On the other hand, `a ? b : c = d` means `a ? b : (c = d)`, suggesting `=` binds stronger.

Does the concept of *operator precedence* in the traditional sense simply not apply here? Why?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B "A precedence table, while mostly adequate, cannot resolve a few details. In particular, note that the ternary operator allows any arbitrary expression as its middle operand, despite being listed as having higher precedence than the assignment and comma operators. Thus a ? b , c : d is interpreted as a ? (b, c) : d, and not as the meaningless (a ? b), (c : d). Also, note that the immediate, unparenthesized result of a C cast expression cannot be the operand of sizeof." But that's referring to a different edge case.

Comment: Wikipedia also notes that in `C` it's described as `logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression`, different than C++

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh, that comma thing is interesting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?:` and `=` have the same operator precedence, and bind right-to-left.

See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Interesting. I guess I was thrown off by the fact that other resources [like this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/126fe14k.aspx) claim that `?:` binds tighter than `=`.